# Docker deamon fails on service start

Tags: docker, centos7

I have docker set up on my CentOS server. It worked fine for a while, until it just stopped working. I tried starting docker service, but I get this error below.

```
$> sudo systemctl start docker.service
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

on executing status command, I get the following error.

```
$> systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-01-13 16:01:39 UTC; 19s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 7263 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-current daemon --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $ADD_REGISTRY $BLOCK_REGISTRY $INSECURE_REGISTRY (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7263 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I tried deleting /var/lib/docker and also re-install docker, but nothing seems to work.

Could you please help me solving this issue?

Thank You!

Comment: The error gave you a second tip, have you found out what `journalctl -xe"` tells you?

Comment: $> journal -xe 
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --

Comment: You've got bigger problems than just Docker not starting.

Comment: @MichaelHampton .. lol, I figured that out :) could you say why?